# Why does Maven2 check for updates of stax-ex at every build?

Tags: maven-2, stax, artifactory

Maven2 checks for updates of stax-ex at every build. And it's just checking this single dependency, all other dependencies are updated only once per day.

Maven2 output:

> artifact org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex: checking for updates from java.net

stax-ex (groupid: org.jvnet.staxex, version: 1.2) is included as part of jaxws-rt (groupid: com.sun.xml.ws, version: 2.1.3). We have an artifactory repository as intermediary.

What could I do? ( Building offline would be an unpopular work-around.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have remote repository declarations in your POMs that bypass your enterprise repository. If you are using Artifactory you can either have remote repository references in POMs [automatically stripped off](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Virtual+Repositories) on a virtual repository level, or configure [mirror-any](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Artifacts+Resolution) in your settings to enforce artifact resolution go strictly through your Artifactory.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and wanted to get to the bottom of it!

The problem is in the [pom.xml file of streambuffer](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/stream/buffer/streambuffer/0.9/streambuffer-0.9.pom) (a dependency of jaxws-rt), which doesn't specify a version for stax-ex. Instead, it uses `RELEASE`, meaning the latest released version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
  <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
  <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This forces Maven to check constantly for the latest release of stax-ex (even if jaxws-rt itself requests version 1.2), by downloading its corresponding `maven-metadata.xml`.

An easy workaround is to force the version of stax-ex in a `dependencyManagement` section of your pom.xm:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.staxex</groupId>
      <artifactId>stax-ex</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And then Maven will stop bothering you about this warning...